# How to find the solutions of the congruence $15x^2 + 19 ＝ 5 \pmod {11}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I understand how to do the question if it is in the form of $ax = b \pmod{11}$, but it has $x^2$ and I am stuck.

How should I solve this kind of question?

Comment: For a small modulus, just try them all.  You only have $11$ choices here. If the modulus is less than a couple thousand, put it in a spreadsheet and sort the results.  If you have a programming language and the modulus is not too many millions, the same.  What tools do you have available?  If it is homework (which I suspect), what tools are you expected to use?  probably you should factor the quadratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First simplify:
$$15x^2+19\equiv5\pmod{11}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad x^2\equiv2\pmod{11}\ .$$
Then just use trial and error.  There are sophisticated techniques in some cases, but for a small modulus like $11$ they are scarcely worth bothering.  So just try $x\equiv0,1,\ldots,10$ until you have found two solutions or none.

Comment: How did you get rid of 15 and 19?

Comment: Exactly as you would if it were $15x+19\equiv5\pmod{11}$.  You said in your question that you know how to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I would first find the inverse using euclidean algorithm, then multiply both side by the inverse if it is ax = b (mod m) form. But I can't find the inverse in this form.

Answer (score 0):

Same as usual, but we can simplify it
$$15x^2+195\equiv 4x^2+8 \equiv b \mod 11$$
for simplicity lets have $b=9$
$$4x^2+8 \equiv 9\implies 4x^2\equiv 1$$
what number times $4$ gives rest $1$ when divided by $11$? $3$ so we have
$$x^2\equiv 3$$
same again, what number squared gives remainder $3$ when divided by $11$? $5$ and $6$ does
ergo
$$x_1=5$$
$$x_2=6$$

Comment: Note that there was a typo in the title, which has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Start as you normally would and simplify the equation:

$15x^2+195\equiv5\pmod{11}$

$4x^2+8\equiv5\pmod{11}$

$4x^2+3\equiv0\pmod{11}$

$4x^2\equiv8\pmod{11}$

$x^2\equiv2\pmod{11}$

We can now write it as a diophantine equation:

$x^2=11y+2$

This is easiest solved by trial and error, just increase y and look at each case. You only need to consider up to $y=10$.

Looking at those cases we find there is no integer solution.